# List all mounts in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

I know `mount` and `df` lists all mounts. But I would like to list the mounts which failed to establish on boot, too. How do I get them?

Comment: Can you look through /etc/fstab and/or grep mount /var/log/dmesg?

Comment: df -aTh from nixcraft

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no such command, since there is no list of "attempted mounts". You can compare the current mount list (`/etc/mtab`) to the list of shares registered to be mounted though (`/etc/fstab`).

Alternatively you could try to `grep` through the system log files to find failed mount attempts.

Comment: cool thanks. If I just remove the line of the mount I don´t want there. Does that work ?

Comment: Well, you can remove a line from `/etc/fstab` which is where typically shares are listed to be mounted at root time, though not only. It depends on the options in each line. The changes in there will be picked up instantly, so they are also considered during the next system reboot. You _cannot_ remove a line from `/etc/mtab`, that is not an ordinary file but created on-the-fly. Think of it as read-only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mount -a` to mount all the mount points defined in the `fstab`.

If there is some kind of error mounting, you will get some warning. If the mount point is already mounted successfully, the command will do nothing with that mountpoint.

Mount errors should appear in `dmesg`.

Comment: Bro but his question is "List currently mounted mount points" not "Mount all mount points" '-'